# Change text colour if number positive in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am loading data from a JSON using javascript. I have managed to load everything into a table. For one column if the number is positive, I want the CSS color to change to green. Else, I want the color to be red. After searching from some questions, I tried the code below and it does not change the colors although the id is 100% correct (it is an ID and not a class). Also there is no `!important` line in my CSS:

```
var resultEl = document.getElementById('highlight');


    var resultVal = platform_data[i][3];
    resultEl.innerHTML = Number(resultVal);
    if (resultVal > 0) 
    {
        resultEl.style.color = "#99c63a!important";
    } else 
    {
        resultEl.style.color = "#c63a3a!important";
    }
```

I am expecting the above to work and I am not getting any errors in the console. I even tried removing the `!important` tag from the `script`.

Snippet:

```js
var json_data = {"headers":["tt","tt","tt","tt","ttt","tt"],"rows":[["v2",226026.36999998972,221971.99999999144,0.01826523165083179,2407556.1300007524,514000],["v1",201656.91999999149,null,"NaN",272595.8799999832,323000],[" v3",185949.95999999763,173707.60999999757,0.07047676264730277,1896453.7399997683,434000],["v4",6889.369999999999,null,"NaN",6889.369999999999,null]]}

  var platform_data = json_data.rows; 
  var table = '<thead><tr><th><h1>AAA</h1></th><th><h1>BBBB</h1></th><th><h1>CCCC</h1></th><th><h1>DDDD</h1></th><th><h1>EEEE</h1></th><th><h1>FFFF</h1></th></tr></thead><tbody>';
  for (var i in platform_data)
 {
  table+='<tr>' + '<td>' + platform_data[i][0] + '</td>' + '<td>$' + platform_data[i][1].toFixed(2) + '</td>' + '<td>$' +  (platform_data[i][2] || 0).toFixed(2) + '</td>' + '<td class="highlight">' + (parseFloat(platform_data[i][3])*100).toFixed(2)  + '%</td>' + '<td>$'+ platform_data[i][4].toFixed(2) +'</td>'+ '<td>$'+ (platform_data[i][5] || 0).toFixed(2) +'</td>'+'</tr>';
 }
  
  table+= '</tbody>';
  document.getElementById("dynamic_table").innerHTML = table;
  





for (var i in platform_data)
 {
  var resultEl = document.getElementsByClassName("highlight")[i];
  
    var resultVal = Number(platform_data[i][3]);
    console.log(resultEl.innerHTML);
    if (resultVal > 0) 
    {
        resultEl.style.color = "#99c63a";
        console.log("green");
        
    } 
    else 
    {
        resultEl.style.color = "#c63a3a";
        console.log("red");
    }
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

body {
overflow:hidden;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.42em;
  color:#454545;
  text-transform:capitalize;
  background:#99C63A url('http://www.fitfactoryma.com/FitFactory/media/SiteResources/redesign/join-now.jpg');
}

#dynamic_table th h1 {
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 1em;
  text-align: left;
  color: #454545;
}

#dynamic_table td {
   font-weight: normal;
   font-size: 1em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #99C63A;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #99C63A;
         box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #99C63A;
}

#dynamic_table {
   text-align: left;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 99%;
   margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  padding: 0 0 8em 0;
}

#dynamic_table td, #dynamic_table th {
   padding-bottom: 2%;
   padding-top: 2%;
  padding-left:2%;  
}

/* Background-color of the odd rows */
#dynamic_table tr:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color: #fff;
}

/* Background-color of the even rows */
#dynamic_table tr:nth-child(even) {
   background-color: #fff;
}

#dynamic_table th {
   background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#dynamic_table td:first-child { color: #99C63A; }
```

```html
<table id="dynamic_table"></table>
```

UPD: I have to make the code for `class` and not `id`. I have update the snippet.

Comment: its odd that you reference an array element i but your element by id references a fixed field...is this intentional...there's really not enough to understand the reason for that

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Ele Please check

Comment: That is not a MINIMAL example...

Comment: @NicoHaase I removed the unwanted CSS lines. I have to make it work for class and id.

Comment: @ApoloRadomer your code appears to work now:
 https://jsfiddle.net/vhgf3xfp/

Comment: @Frish I changed it again and it works now. I might update it if I find anything interesting.

Comment: I tested your code and I got red and green colors working correctly.
Can you give more details (browser, version) and also the order you put your code (css, html, js) and if you are including other css

Comment: It works fine. I just had a problem with getElements and getElement. So, syntax error. Before, I had to add a for loop for each td.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You adding `<td class="highlight">` in table variable

But getting element by id

```
var resultEl = document.getElementById('highlight')
```

Just traverse the highlight class

```
[]
  .slice
  .call(document.querySelectorAll('.highlight'))
  .forEach(function (el) {
    // check value here
    var elValue = el.textContent.replace('%', '')
    if (Number(elValue) > 0) {
      el.style.color = 'red'
    } else {
      el.style.color = 'blue'
    }
  })
```